# How is it possible to pass attributes to child rules in boost spirit karma

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

I am parsing text into an AST via qi and generates text again via karma. This is working as expected, but wants some method to pass on an attribute from one rule to another.

**Ported from the comments**:

<kbd>[Current Code On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/68becc156e4bee4b)</kbd>

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_adt.hpp>
#include <fstream>

  struct c_struct
  {
    int value1;
  };

  struct b_struct
  {
    std::string value1;
    std::vector< c_struct > value2;
  };

  struct a_struct
  { 
    std::string value1;
    std::vector< b_struct > value2;
  };

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( c_struct,    
    (int, value1)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( b_struct,    
    (std::string, value1)
    (std::vector< c_struct >, value2)
)

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT( a_struct,    
    (std::string, value1)
    (std::vector< b_struct >, value2)
)

using namespace boost::spirit;
using namespace boost::spirit::qi;
using namespace boost::spirit::karma;
using namespace boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator>
struct grammarB : karma::grammar<Iterator, a_struct()>
{
  grammarB() : grammarB::base_type(ruleA)
  {
    ruleA %= karma::string << karma::lit(' ') << +ruleB << eps;
    ruleB %= karma::string << +ruleC << karma::lit(' ') << eps;    
    ruleC %= lit("  ->  ") << karma::int_;
  }

  karma::rule<Iterator, a_struct()> ruleA;
  karma::rule<Iterator, b_struct()> ruleB;
  karma::rule<Iterator, c_struct()> ruleC;
};

template <typename Iterator>
struct grammarA : qi::grammar<Iterator, a_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type>
{
  grammarA() : grammarA::base_type(ruleA)
  {
    ruleA %= ruleString >> omit[+qi::char_('.')] >> +ruleB;
    ruleB %= ruleString >> omit[qi::char_(',')] >> (ruleC % qi::char_(',')) >> omit[qi::char_(';')];
    ruleC %= qi::int_;

    ruleString %= +qi::char_("a-z");
  }           
  qi::rule<Iterator, a_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleA;   
  qi::rule<Iterator, b_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleB;  
  qi::rule<Iterator, c_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleC;

  qi::rule<Iterator, std::string(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleString;
};    

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
  std::string storage("parent ... whee,4,5,6;ahhhh,5,6;"); // We will read the contents here.

  typedef grammarA<std::string::const_iterator> grammarA_t;
  grammarA_t grammar;
  a_struct ast;

  std::string::const_iterator iter = storage.begin();
  std::string::const_iterator end = storage.end();

  bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, boost::spirit::ascii::space, ast);

  if (r && iter == end)
  {    
    std::cout << "Parsing succeeded" << std::endl;

    typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> output_iterator_type;

    std::string generated;    
    output_iterator_type sink(generated);

    typedef grammarB<output_iterator_type> grammarB_t; 
    grammarB_t generator;


    if ( generate(sink, generator, ast) )
        std::cout << generated << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "fail" << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

It prints

```
Parsing succeeded
parent whee  ->  4  ->  5  ->  6 ahhhh  ->  5  ->  6
```

But I'd prefer it to print

```
Parsing succeeded
parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6
```

Is this possible, and how?

Comment: There is no AST. There's no generator API invocation (neither iterator nor stream based). There's no bound attributes. Exactly what do want to achieve? "wheee", "cool" and "childish" seem to have been achieved. _Hint:_ loose the noise, and show a SSCCE/MVCE

Comment: SSCCE as requested at [link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/52a2e4ff2ed8ed84).

Comment: As asked I would know if is possible to access/pass a given rule attribute from other rules and hereby be able to do the same as above. It should be noted that I have changed the naming of the rules in the source link.

Comment: The SSCCE is looking promising. You should really include the minimalized version of that in the question, but lemme look at it. I might reduce it for you in the process of reading :/

Comment: You don't specify the desired outcome. It's hard to "guess" what you mean by this "specification" in the form of dream code that (a) doesn't compile (b) doesn't show what you want it to actually look like (c) doesn't show what it would do, even if it were realistic code. I'll keep reading the linked sample just in case the penny drops there (but since it does compile, I have a suspicion, it won't help)

Comment: (a) The code in the link compiles just fine in VS12, parsing the storage string fine into the output "parent whee  ->  4  ->  5  ->  6 ahhhh  ->  5  ->  6". (b) Thought the karma grammar in it self was the answer to what the output should look like (c) Do not know what this means, as the source compiles and works just fine. As to support your confusion, then I would like to get output such as "parent parent whee  ->  parent 4  ->  parent 5  -> parent 6 ahhhh  -> parent 5  ->  parent 6". As to my question: How to get an attribute value from a parent rule to some other child rule.

Comment: (a) I know, that's what I _said_ in my previous comment (b) no the karma grammar shows a lot of frivolous prose inside a non-realistic karma grammar (c) the output is what you expect to be generated (duh). I'll see if I can wrap my head around this sample: "parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6".

Comment: I reverse engineered your question into proper form. I honestly think it'd be clearer if you remove the original "non-code" sample. I left it in for context now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay. The sample of output `"parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6"` actually made things /almost/ clear.

I think there's an inconsistency, since **either** you would expect

```
parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 parent ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6
```

**or** you would expect

```
parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6
```

I'll show you both.

```
ruleA %= string [ _pass_along = _1 ] << +ruleB(_pass_along);
ruleB  = string << +ruleC(_inherited);
//ruleB  = lit(_inherited) << string << +ruleC(_inherited); // alternative interpretation
ruleC  = "->" << lit(_inherited) << karma::int_;
```

This uses both [`karma::locals<>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/generator_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.karma.reference.generator_concepts.nonterminal.locals) and [inherited attributes](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/generator_concepts/nonterminal.html#spirit.karma.reference.generator_concepts.nonterminal.signature).

Notes:

- I've simplified both the Qi and Karma rules
- favour delimiters in Karma rules
- use `lexeme` where appropriate in the Qi rules ([Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965))
- use `lit("x")` instead of `string("x")` if you don't want to synthesize an attribute
- drop `lit()` unless non-spirit domain expression template operator overloads would be selected
- use `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES`
- Do *not* mix `using namespace`s. There's no need and it *will* lead to trouble.

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a78903efdd9e7d7b)</kbd>**

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/phoenix.hpp>

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

struct c_struct {
    int value1;
};

struct b_struct {
    std::string value1;
    std::vector<c_struct> value2;
};

struct a_struct {
    std::string value1;
    std::vector<b_struct> value2;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(c_struct, (int, value1))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(b_struct, (std::string, value1)(std::vector<c_struct>, value2))
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(a_struct, (std::string, value1)(std::vector<b_struct>, value2))

namespace qi    = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;
namespace ascii = boost::spirit::ascii;

template <typename Iterator> struct generator : karma::grammar<Iterator, a_struct(), karma::space_type> {
    generator() : generator::base_type(start) {
        using namespace karma;
        _a_type _pass_along;
        _r1_type _inherited;

        start = ruleA;

        ruleA %= string [ _pass_along = _1 ] << +ruleB(_pass_along);
        ruleB  = string << +ruleC(_inherited);
        //ruleB  = lit(_inherited) << string << +ruleC(_inherited); // alternative interpretation
        ruleC  = "->" << lit(_inherited) << karma::int_;

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(ruleA)(ruleB)(ruleC))
    }

    karma::rule<Iterator, a_struct(), karma::space_type> start;
    karma::rule<Iterator, a_struct(), qi::locals<std::string>, karma::space_type> ruleA;
    karma::rule<Iterator, b_struct(std::string const&), karma::space_type> ruleB;
    karma::rule<Iterator, c_struct(std::string const&), karma::space_type> ruleC;
};

template <typename Iterator> struct grammar : qi::grammar<Iterator, a_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> {
    grammar() : grammar::base_type(ruleA) {
        using namespace qi;
        ruleA = ruleString >> lexeme[+qi::lit('.')] >> +ruleB;
        ruleB = ruleString >> ',' >> (ruleC % ',') >> ';';
        ruleC = qi::int_;

        ruleString = +qi::char_("a-z");

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((ruleA)(ruleB)(ruleC)(ruleString))
    }
    qi::rule<Iterator, a_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleA;
    qi::rule<Iterator, b_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleB;
    qi::rule<Iterator, c_struct(), boost::spirit::ascii::space_type> ruleC;

    qi::rule<Iterator, std::string()/*, boost::spirit::ascii::space_type*/> ruleString;
};

int main() {
    typedef std::string::const_iterator It;
    std::string const storage("parent ... whee,4,5,6;ahhhh,5,6;"); // We will read the contents here.

    grammar<It> grammar;
    a_struct ast;

    It iter = storage.begin(), end = storage.end();
    bool r = phrase_parse(iter, end, grammar, ascii::space, ast);

    if (r && iter == end) {
        std::cout << "Parsing succeeded" << std::endl;

        generator<boost::spirit::ostream_iterator> generator;

        std::cout << "'parent whee  ->  4  ->  5  ->  6 ahhhh  ->  5  ->  6 ' // ORIGINAL\n";
        std::cout << "'parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ' // DESIRED/EXPECTED\n";
        std::cout << "'" << karma::format_delimited(generator, karma::space, ast) << "' // ACTUAL\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Parsing succeeded
'parent whee  ->  4  ->  5  ->  6 ahhhh  ->  5  ->  6 ' // ORIGINAL
'parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ' // DESIRED/EXPECTED
'parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ' // ACTUAL
```

If you uncomment the alternative `ruleB` generator:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2b70dc47d990e23c)</kbd>**

Output:

```
Parsing succeeded
'parent whee  ->  4  ->  5  ->  6 ahhhh  ->  5  ->  6 ' // ORIGINAL
'parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ' // DESIRED/EXPECTED
'parent parent whee -> parent 4 -> parent 5 -> parent 6 parent ahhhh -> parent 5 -> parent 6 ' // ACTUAL
```

Comment: Got some questions:

**1:** "generate_delimited" adds delimiters to the output. Is there any other reason for this generator except for proper spacing in the output? Guess "generate" is as applicable if delimitation is not needed.

**2:** Can it be assumed that use of "_a_type"/"_r1_type" and use of locals is a general solution to solve this problem? It seems as this implementation easily can be extended for more complex use.

**3:** Why did you not use the default phoenix or spirit _a/_r1 variables? I might have missed something in the documentation.

Comment: @DevDev **1:** Yes it's there for the same reason you were manually inserting the whitespace. And yes if it was not needed, it was not needed. **2:** Erm. Yes. I linked to the documentation **3:** I prefer readable code.

Comment: Anyone reading this: This is a very good and comprehensive feedback which solved my issue. Hats off for helping and showing how to properly ask a question. Thanks

Comment: Hrm. Your comment was ~8 hours later than [that edit](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/29133268/2) :) Thanks for the kind words